# How to use Windows & Form both authentications into a single Web application?

Tags: asp.net, windows, forms, authentication, web-config

I have a web application in which currently we are using windows authentication but now my currently requirement is that I want to implement windows & form both authentication into a single application.

When windows authenticated system opens application in that case login form will not display and if another user open application login form will display.

Please let me know how it is possible into a single application?

Comment: WIF ( windows identity framework). This works with both windows authentication and forms.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible . Create a httpmodule and implement the

```
                 Authenticate_Request
```

Check if user is under the domain if yes validate against AD otherwise redirect to form authentication